# How to learn ADO.NET

Tags: ado.net

I need to learn ADO.NET to build applications based on MS Office. I have read a good deal about ADO.NET in the MSDN Library, but everything seems rather messy to me.

What are the basics one must figure out when using ADO.NET? I think a few key words will suffice to let me organize my learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three key components (assuming ur using SQL server):

- `SQLConnection`
- `SqlCommand`
- `SqlDataReader`

(if you're using something else, replace `Sql` with "Something", like `MySqlConnection`, `OracleCommand`)

Everything else is just built on top of that.

**Example 1:**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING"))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
  command.commandText = "SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Status = @OnlineStatus";
  command.Connection = connection;
  command.Parameters.Add("@OnlineStatus", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1; //replace with enum
  connection.Open();

  using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader))
  {
      List<string> onlineUsers = new List<string>();

      while (dr.Read())
      {
         onlineUsers.Add(dr.GetString(0));
      }
  }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING"))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
{
  command.commandText = "DELETE FROM Users where Email = @Email";
  command.Connection = connection;
  command.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "user@host.com";
  connection.Open();
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of getting a command object is to call `connection.CreateCommand()`.

That way you shouldn't have to set the `Connection` property on the command object.